# Why is Libreoffice calc 7.0.4.2 slow in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, display-settings

When opening Libreoffice Calc 7.0.4.2 as of today, in Windows 10 Pro 20H2, with Nvidia GPU 1070 Max-Q and i7-7700HQ, even on a blank sheet, the following actions induce a ~0.7s lag or more:

- clicking on a cell
- typing in a cell (going from "empty cell" to "something displaying in the cell as it is typed")
- hitting "Tab" to switch between cells

Some threads on the net suggested unchecking "anti aliasing" in Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> View --> Graphics Output; however, in my case, this did not work, as for many people apparently.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, what worked instantly was the following:

1. Going to Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> View --> Graphics Output
2. Unchecking the box with "Use Skia for all rendering"

A [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreoffice/comments/imai7h/libreoffice_is_too_slow_on_windows_10_can_anyone/) mentions this, but since it is archived, there is no way to up-vote this answer which is buried down the thread.

[Skia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine) appears to be an open source 2D graphics library. Libreoffice devs, if you are reading this, fixing this issue would be great. Thank you!